# Python to go through multiple folders and process files inside them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple folders than contain about 5-10 files each. What I am trying to do is go to the next folder when finishing processing files from the previous folders and start working on the new files. I have this code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Training Sets"): #Path that contains folders
    for i in dirs: #if I don't have this, an error is shown in line 4 that path needs to be str and not list
        for file in i: #indexing files inside the folders
            path = os.path.join(i, files) #join path of the files
            dataset = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', header = None) #reading the files
            trainSet = dataset.values.tolist() #some more code
            editedSet = dataset.values.tolist() #some more code
            #rest of the code...
```

The problem is that it doesn't do anything. Not even printing if I add prints for debugging.

Comment: is your `dataset ` variable empty

Comment: what do you mean? after the file is read the content is saved in the dataset variable.

Comment: yes does dataset contain anything?

Comment: of course, the files contain numbers

Comment: I meant does dataset variable contain anything, is it able to read? if yes then what exactly do you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, be sure that you are in the correct top-level directory (i.e. the one containing "Training Sets". You can check this with `os.path.abspath(os.curdir)`. Otherwise, the code does nothing since it does not find the directory to walk.

`os.walk` does the directory walking for you. The key is understanding root (the path to the current directory), dirs (a list of subdirectories) and files (a list of files in the current directory). You don't actually need dirs.

So your code is two loops:

```
>>> for root, dirs, files in os.walk("New Folder1"): #Path that contains folders
...     for file in files: #indexing files inside the folders
...             path = os.path.join(root, file) #join path of the files
...             print(path) # Your code here
...
New Folder1\New folder1a\New Text Document.txt
New Folder1\New folder1b\New Text Document2.txt
```

Comment: I have moved the source file one directory back from the directory that the folders are so there will only be the folders inside.